# Watch log dir for new file, automatically tail to slack

Tags: file, bash, linux

We have a process that outputs to log files in the format `/var/log/xxx/YYYY_MM_DD.log` - the file name is chosen programmatically and is not rotated using logrotate or anything like that. We want to automatically tail the latest file and pipe that to [slackcat](https://github.com/paulhammond/slackcat) so that we can see the logs in a certain slack channel.

I came up with the following solution that works great, but I'm no bash expert so I am wondering if this could be simplified? The hardest part was avoiding zombie processes when something dies or gets killed, but I'd love to do this with one file instead of 2 also:

**`watchlogdir.sh`**

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "pkill -TERM -g $$; exit" INT TERM EXIT
    while true; do
      /root/tailtoslack.sh &
      PID=$!
      echo $PID
      echo $$
  inotifywait -e create /var/log/xxx/
  pkill -TERM -P $PID
  kill $PID
done
```

**`tailtoslack.sh`**

```
while true; do
    FILETOWATCH=`ls -t /var/log/xxx/*.log | head -1`
    tail $FILETOWATCH -f -n1 | grep -v "DEBUG:\|^$" --color=never --line-buffered | /root/slackcat &> /tmp/slackcat
    sleep 31
done
```

The core of `watchlogdir.sh`, besides the interruption handling stuff, is using `inotifywait` to watch for a new file created in the log directory, and when that happens, killing `tailtoslack.sh` and respawning it so it can find the new file

`tailtoslack.sh` just looks for the latest file, and pipes that to slackcat after filtering out `DEBUG` lines and empty lines. the while loop here is because some lines in the error logs cause `slackcat` to crash, so this way if that happens it'll sleep for a little while and retry.

Without changing the requirements of how the log files are written, can any of this be done better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems quite fine. Given your circumstances, I don't see how this can be done simpler.

<del>The script could use a bit of tidying up though. The indentation of `watchlogdir.sh` is haphazard, it would be more readable to make it consistent.</del> Oh I see now. It's the `$$` that messes things up, your formatting is fine.

In the other script, this line could be written better:

> ```
> FILETOWATCH=`ls -t /var/log/xxx/*.log | head -1`
> ```

By using `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` for command substitution, and using the canonical option `-n1` instead of `-1` with `head`:

```
FILETOWATCH=$(ls -t /var/log/xxx/*.log | head -n1)
```

Comment: thanks! As you can see, stackexchange seems to be doing something weird to the indentation, I  can't figure out why but it is in fact sane in the actual file.

Comment: uggh, I see. Amended my post

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`! At least use the `-1` option to guarantee only one entry per line!

Comment: @DavidFoerster I don't think that getting the first line of `ls` is really parsing. I think that recommendation concerns parsing the content of lines, especially the output of `ls -l`. I also don't see how `-1` has an effect on the pipeline to `| head -n1`. As far as I know it only affects display in an interactive shell. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I never thought of the different defaults for interactive and non-interactive output. Makes sense though. +1